# Jquery ui slide content along with scroll bar

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Well i'm totaly lost here, i am using jquery ui `slider`widget to make this quite simple menu but i just can't figure out a basic formula to make menu items slide along with with scroll bar.

Here is jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/n2H6Q/4/

**Please** keep in mind that `content` height can change to any value that's why i have use **random** height, **and** `container` height can as well change to any value, that's why it is so difficult for me to figure out how to deal with all these numbers...

Any kind of help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you should be setting height of `container` as random, not the `content`. Here's an edited version of your [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n2H6Q/6/).

Edit: if content height is less than container height, scrollbar should not appear. I didn't take that into account.

Comment: Yes you are correct, im quite tired so i made a few mistakes by setting up this example, anyways it looks like it's working now, im going to take a closer look tomorrow and see if everything is fine now